# How to install a BETA aplication through another application in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, beta-testing, webclient

how can I install an application from the BETA market on a WP7? ( the person in question would be using the Windwos Live ID that I have out on the mailing list ( ppl who can install the BETA app on their registrated device ) ). I came up with this:

```
 WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask( );
        browser.URL = deeplink;
        browser.Show( );
```

But I would like it to look a lot neater than that. For example, now the Browser will start up, coming to a page where you have to still press ( continue or something ) |
What I would really likem is for the browser ( if used at all ) run in the background, and let WebClient download the app from the app itself. ( is this even possible? )
greetz and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MarketplaceDetailTask` with the GUID of the beta application (this is the long part of the deep-link URL). It will directly launch the Marketplace app on the phone. Then the beta-user should be able to download your app as any other app they would get from Marketplace.

The GUID is the long string after "?appId=" in your deep link URL.

[See MSDN docs for MarketplaceDetailTask.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacedetailtask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) You'll have to specify the GUID of your app in 
the `ContentIdentifier` property.

Comment: Thanks =D I had understood that this was disabled for the Beta market.